# The menu background i want it to be 100% width with no left, right and top gaps

Tags: javascript, css

The menu background color should be full width, and should be full screen on 24 inch and below. Here is an image what it looks like. The website url is also in the image.

[image: header menu image]

Below is the scss where i added the background color. Please can someone edit the below code so the background colour is touching left right and top (on top there is a little gap),

```css
.header-main-wrapper {
    max-width: 1720px;
    margin: 0 auto;
    background: #1c2e52;
    @media #{$xs,$sm,$md,$lg} {
        padding: 16px 0;
```

I tried using inspect in chrome but to no avail. Could not find anything on stackflow to solve it.

Comment: You have `max-width: 1720px;` so that element cannot be wider than 1720px.  Add another element on the outside of the wrapper and give it the same background color

Comment: There are a lot of reasons why your CSS is not behaving in the desired fashion. It would help a lot to include your HTML in case the `.header-main-wrapper` element is constrained also by the parent.

Comment: @jme11 can you write an element so that i can use it?

Comment: You can [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75656800/edit) your question to add relevant HTML: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0):

There's already another div around the `.header-main-wrapper` with the Bootstrap class of `container-fluid`.  Just add another class it that is unique, so that you can apply the background color to it without affecting any other containers on your page.  I called it `container-background`:

```html
<div class="container-fluid container-background"> <!-- add class here -->
  <div class="header-main-wrapper">
                ... 
  </div>
</div>
```

Then, in your SCSS or CSS file add:

```css
.container-background {
  background: #1c2e52;
}
```